# I have a java authorizer lambda which generates policy on aws s3 to upload/get files : getting 403 access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::{mybucket}/"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": "statement1"
    }
}
```

I am accessing api from rest client with aws api gateway url...After my lambda returning policy(above) to api gateway in the end of logs showing message : 'The client is not authorized to perform this operation.'
Please let me know if i am missing anything...Thanks in advance

Comment: Googled for **error 403** ?

Comment: I was preparing policy for S3 instead of policy for api gateway. Got clarity from here...
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

Answer (score 1):

Please pass the x-API-key as a header with the correct value of the API key that is associated with the API Gateway while making the request.

You have to pass 'x-API-key' HTTP Header Parameter to API Gateway.

The API Key had to be created.

In addition, you need to check a usage plan for the API Key on the API Gateway Console.